# Android network socket design

Tags: java, android, sockets, udp

We have an application that is transmitting and receiving data. The idea is to have bidirectional transmit and receive of messages.

For incoming messages, we have our system running the following technique:

```
public void run() {
    try {
        socket = new DatagramSocket(null);
        socket.bind(new InetSocketAddress(port));
        socket.setReuseAddress(true);

        while (!Thread.currentThread().isInterrupted() && bContinue) {
            DatagramPacket packet = new DatagramPacket(buf, buf.length);

            socket.receive(packet);

            processPacket(packet)
        }
    } catch (SocketException e) {
        Log.v(TAG, "Socket closed exception");
    } catch (Exception e) {
        Log.e(TAG, "Error starting the socket listener");
        e.printStackTrace();
        return;
    }

    if (socket != null) {
        // Socket teardown omitted...
    }
}
```

This seems to work great for receiving packets as they come in. Where my question lies is in the transmission of packets. The two schools of thought were to either

1. Create a single thread per packet that will send a message
2. Create a single thread that receives messages from a queue and sends them out

Pseudocode for the two methods would be something like:

```
public void run1() {
    socket.open();
    socket.sendMessage();
    socket.close();
}

public void run2() {
    socket.open();
    while (1) {
        message = BlockingMessageQueue.take();
        socket.send(message);
    }
    socket.close();
}
```

The former would open, send, and close every time a packet is being received or transmitted. The latter creates a single thread that waits for packets and sends them out one at a time.

Is there any benefit to doing the former vs the latter? Packets are typically sent every 10 seconds, so is there any design flaw in "keeping a socket open" in a separate thread? I'm used to the embedded world where a program design would be to start only threads that are necessary, and to have them block as much as possible. Some designs I've seen extensively use timers to start threads for things like packet transmission, which is a convention I'm not used to.

Thanks for the help!